# Strange behaviour of #ifdef defined() in C++

Tags: c++, macros, conditional-compilation, defined

I was writing cross platform code in Visual Studio Community, using C++20 and I am stuck on the output of following code:

```
#define WINDOWS (defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__))
#define UNIX (defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix))

constexpr bool is_unix1()
{
#ifdef UNIX
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}

constexpr bool is_unix2()
{
#ifdef defined(UNIX)
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}


int main()
{
    cout << std::boolalpha << is_unix1() << " " << is_unix2() << endl;
}
```

When I ran this code in windows, from inside VS Community itself, I got the following output:

```
true false
```

Can someone explain why `is_unix1()` is evaluated as `false` while `is_unix2()` is evaluated as `true`?

I came to know that `defined(...)` is compiler specific, and it is not part of standard C++. But directly using the macro is resulting in strange behavior, and I am stuck on which approach to use here.

Comment: It's either `#ifdef` or `#if defined(...)`

Comment: `is_unix1()` returns `true` because the code has a definition of a macro named `UNIX`. `#ifdef` doesn’t care what the definition is, only that it exists.

Comment: You want `#if UNIX`. You want to check the value of the macro, not the fact that it's defined, because in your code it's always defined. Alternatively, you can define it conditionally, along the lines of `#if defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix) \n #define UNIX \n #endif` (replace `\n` with actual line ends). Then you can check it with `#ifdef UNIX` or `#if defined(UNIX)`

Comment: I was stuck on this for one hour and didn't realize the mistake... Thanks for the quick response!!

Comment: Use of `defined()` is not portable if it is produced as a result of *expanding a macro* (I believe - but haven't checked - the behaviour is undefined, so a diagnostic is not required).   With compilers/preprocessors that allow it,  your code `#ifdef UNIX` will always test true, since you have defined `UNIX` to be something (`#ifdef` only tests if a macro is defined, not what the result of expanding it is).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`defined` is not compiler-specific. It is specified in the C++ standard.

`#ifdef defined(UNIX)` is simply not valid syntax and a compiler must diagnose this. `#ifdef` must be followed by a single identifier and then a new-line. It conditionally compiles code based on whether or not the identifier is defined as a macro.

`#ifdef UNIX` therefore always compiles the then-branch, because you defined `UNIX` as a macro beforehand.

What you want seems to be something like

```
#if (defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix))
```

`#if` conditionally compiles based on a given expression which can include `defined` operators, which individually evaluate to `0` or `1` depending on whether the identifier is defined as a macro.

However, you can't hide `(defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix))` behind the `UNIX` macro and then have it expand in the controlling `#if` expression. If such an expansion results in the `defined` token, the behavior of the program is undefined.

So what you really want instead of your definition for `UNIX` is

```
#if (defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix))
#define UNIX
#endif
```

And then later

```
#ifdef UNIX
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answer. Can you confirm if we can replace `#ifdef` with `#if` in my code above without changing `#define UNIX`? Based on the comments on my question, it seems like that approach should work too

Comment: @AakashGupta No, that has undefined behavior as I wrote in my answer. See https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.cond#10.sentence-2.